# how to set static ip in ubuntu 16.04 on raspberry pi 3 (cloud-init)?

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi, static-ip

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Raspberry pi 3 but when I edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to setup a static ip it gets replaced with default settings on startup.  Looks like `cloud-init` is managing the network settings.  How do you manage `cloud-init`?
Google rendered no help.
Thanks.

Comment: I found a workaround : "sudo apt remove cloud-init"  -- problem solved!

Comment: Any other "official" way to do this? I ended up removing cloud-init, but am wondering whether there is way to configure it using cloud-init

Answer (score -1):

I tried simply apt remove'ing cloud-init on the latest 16.04 server image from Pi Flavour Maker, and it rendered my system unbootable. This tip for a different Ubuntu (probably the official desktop 18.04) warns that there may be other processes that depend on cloud-init, and those dependencies aren't automatically cleared up by removing it:
[gotcha warning about 18.04](https://nucco.org/2018/05/ubuntu-18-04-chronicles-removing-cloud-init.html)

> You just deployed yourself a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 18.04 Bionic
>   Beaver. It should be the latest and greatest, and you just need a
>   virtual machine to do some web development or perhaps you just want to
>   enable IP forwarding and use this machine as a router. That's great,
>   except the latest Ubuntu assumes that you are part of the current
>   trend to put everything in the cloud, and so ships with something
>   called cloud-init.
>
> No harm normally, but this wastes valuable seconds doing something you
>   don't need if you're not in the cloud. It’s easy to remove this
>   package by following the (modified) instructions
>   [here](https://makandracards.com/operations/42688-how-to-remove-cloud-init-from-ubuntu):
>
> ```
> dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init
> ```
>
> Then deselect all the options except *None*.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge cloud-init
> sudo mv /etc/cloud/ ~/; sudo mv /var/lib/cloud/ ~/cloud-lib
> ```
>
> I prefer to move, rather than delete, in case something goes wrong and
>   you wish to restore the files.
>
> When you remove cloud-init following those steps, your machine stops
>   booting and there is apparently a service that is waiting for network
>   to be up. This would normally be just an inconvenience, but the boot
>   hangs indefinitely waiting for said network. Odd choice of
>   configuration out of the box, but anyway, you can fix this by:
>
> - List the services which depend on network being online.
>
>   ```
>   sudo systemctl show -p WantedBy network-online.target
>   ```
>
>   This will list the culprits as some iscsi services that you probably don’t need.
> - Disable the services and remove the open-iscsi package
>
>   ```
>   systemctl disable <service name>
>   sudo apt remove open-iscsi
>   ```
>
> That should do to get the system booting without some service waiting
>   endlessly for a network connection.